# Проблема с написанием триггера (запрос вернул больше одного значения)

Tags: sql, триггер

Доброго времени суток всем!
К сожалению мне плоховато дается SQL. В общем то проблема следующая. Есть у меня небольшая табличка. Есть там столбцы "Дата" и "Смена". Дата пишется со временем, дата особого значения не имеет, а вот время да. Есть 3 варианта: XXXX-XX-XX 00:00:00.000, XXXX-XX-XX 08:00:00.000 и XXXX-XX-XX 16:00:00.000. В зависимости от того какое из этих времен стоит должно быть значение 1,2 или 3 в столбике "Смена". Написал я следующий код:

```
USE [DBCurs]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[Number_Smena]    Script Date: 08.03.2017 15:58:01 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
--====================================
--  Create database trigger template 
--====================================
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Number_Smena] 
ON [dbo].[РабочийПроцесс] 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN 
IF (select cast(dbo.РабочийПроцесс.Дата as time) [time] FROM dbo.РабочийПроцесс )=convert(time,'00:00',101)
      UPDATE dbo.РабочийПроцесс SET Смена = 1  WHERE Смена IN(SELECT Смена)
ELSE IF (select cast(dbo.РабочийПроцесс.Дата as time) [time] FROM dbo.РабочийПроцесс)=convert(time,'08:00',101)
       UPDATE dbo.РабочийПроцесс SET Смена = 2
ELSE
       UPDATE dbo.РабочийПроцесс SET Смена = 3
 END
```

Вытаскиваю тут время из datetime, проверяю его и соответственно присваиваю значение. Если запускать этот код просто как запрос, то значения меняются. А вот если запускать его триггером, то вылезает ошибка:

Строки не были обновлены.

Данные в строке 3 не были зафиксированы.
Источник ошибки: .Net SqlClient Data Provider.
Сообщение об ошибке: Вложенный запрос вернул больше одного значения. Это запрещено, когда вложенный запрос следует после =, !=, <, <=, >, >= или используется в качестве выражения.

Выполнение данной инструкции было прервано.

Насколько я понял по гуглу, проблема моя в том, что этот триггер будет работать только если в таблице есть одна строка, а если их несколько то запрос возвращает несколько значений и соответственно падает. Далее насколько я понял, проблема решается с помощью команд IN, JOIN или EXISTS, но вот как их применить кокнретно к своему случая я вообще не понимаю. В интернете есть примеры, но по ним к сожалению не получается.

Comment: Вам надо определится с тем какие строки вы хотите поменять. И из каких строк взять информацию о дате. Было бы логично делать это не со всеми строками таблицы, а только  с теми, что меняются. Для этого надо    получать данные из таблицы `inserted` и обновлять  только те строки, которые там присутствуют. Но в inserted строк так же может быть несколько ! и следовательно вам надо либо обрабатывать их в цикле по одной, либо, что правильней, сделать все одним запросом. И еще вы не указали в вопросе какая у вас БД и какой версии

Comment: MS SQL Server 2014. Сейчас сделал вот так, вроде работает:IF (select cast(Дата as time) [time] FROM inserted )=convert(time,'00:00',101)

Comment: Действительно тоже не вариант, если редактировать или добавлять несколько строк то тоже проблемы.